# CSS3 Animation not functioning properly in different ways depending on browser

Tags: css, animation, svg, cross-browser

I'm having an issue where my animations aren't working properly, but differently depending on the browser.

In Firefox, it scales and fades properly, but not from the proper origin. In Chrome, it fades, but does not scale.

I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMPyq/4/)

here is my CSS

```
path {
    fill: white;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
.clone {
    -webkit-animation: lookAtMe 0.75s ease-out infinite;
    animation: lookAtMe 0.75s ease-out infinite;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes lookAtMe {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes lookAtMe {
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: I think this is a bug with paths. Look at this example with the same CSS, but using a div: http://jsfiddle.net/BMPyq/7/

Comment: Weird. It was working the other day, when I had several SVGs working on screen, but I guess now that I've thrown them all into one, that isn't gonna cut it anymore. Thanks for the reply. Now I just wish there was a workaround. For now I'll just make another div entirely.

Comment: You're welcome! You might want to see if someone has already reported a Chrome bug about this. Best of luck!